# JAVA - Can't hide button and text field in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a game where the user tries to guess a number between 1 and 10 (or 1 and 100 whatever you set it to be).

I show a button called `btnPlayAgain` when the user either wins or loses asking them if they want to play again. I want to hide that button when the program starts and show it when they win or lose.

I want to set the button that allows you to guess (`btnGuess`) when the `btnPlayAgain` button to be invisible. But for some reason that's not happening. the `btnPlayAgain` button is still visible when the user sees the play again button.

If I try:

```
        else {
            btnGuess.setVisible(false);
            txtGuess.setVisible(false);
            message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
            btnPlayAgain.setVisible(true);
        }
```

The button `btnGuess` does not get hidden when the user guesses right. And the "guess is correct. Let's play again." message does not get printed to the screen.

This is my function that plays the game and it's supporting functions:

```
public void checkGuess() {
    btnPlayAgain.setVisible(false);
    String guessText = txtGuess.getText();
    txtGuess.setText("");// Empties the contents of the text field.
    String message = "";
    try {
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
        if (numberOfTries == 0) {
            btnGuess.setVisible(false);
            txtGuess.setVisible(false);
            message = "You Lost! A new game has begun and you have 8 guesses remaining.";
            btnPlayAgain.setVisible(true);
        }
        else if (guess < theNumber) {
            message = guess + " is too low. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
        }
        else if (guess > theNumber) {
            message = guess + " is too high. Try again. You have " + numberOfTries + " tries left!";
        }
        else {
            btnGuess.setVisible(false);
            txtGuess.setVisible(false);
            message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
            btnPlayAgain.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Enter a whole number between 1 and 10.";
    } finally {
        lblOutput.setText(message);
        txtGuess.requestFocus();
        txtGuess.selectAll();
        
    }
    decrementNumberOfTries();
}

public void newGame() {
    numberOfTries = 8;
    theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
}

public void decrementNumberOfTries() {
    --numberOfTries;        
}
```

And here is a link to [all my code](https://pastebin.com/kdqpRey1).

This is what the window looks like where you play the game:

[image]

I want to hide the `Guess!` button and text field and show the `playAgain` button. The `playAgain` button should allow the user to start a new game. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you made `btnGuess` a local variable in the constructor instead of setting the field, so a `NullPointerException` is thrown when the number is correct. Since you are catching `Exception`, the program assumes that an invalid number was entered. Catch `NumberFormatException` instead to avoid missing errors in the program.

In the constructor, change

```
JButton btnGuess = new JButton("Guess!");
```

To

```
this.btnGuess = new JButton("Guess!");
```

To reset the game properly, you need to modify the `newGame` method to show only the appropriate elements and reset the text of the output label.

```
public void newGame() {
    numberOfTries = 8;
    theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    btnGuess.setVisible(true);
    txtGuess.setVisible(true);
    btnPlayAgain.setVisible(false);
    lblOutput.setText("Enter a number above and click Guess!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. But for some reason when I press the `btnPlayAgain` button nothing happens. I try to start a new game when you press that button: `  btnPlayAgain = new JButton("Play Again!");
  btnPlayAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    newGame();
   }
  });`  Any idea why the `btnPlayAgain` button isn't doing it's thing?

Comment: In general, try not to catch an unspecified `Exception`, instead catch more specific ones, in this case `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just added that to my code. I'd still like to find out how to get the `btnPlayAgain` button working.